# How to wait for promise to resolve in Firefox console

Tags: javascript, firefox, promise

i have developer console open up in Firefox and have to work with some promises. I would really really apreciate some blocking syntax, which would just wait for the promise to resolve and directly return the result. Right now i have to do something like:

```
var result; promise.then((res) => { result = res})
```

every time which i'm really tired of. I tried something like this:

```
resolve = function(promise) { var res; var done = false; promise.then(r => {res = r; done = true}); while(!done) {}; return res; }
```

But it stucks forever. Is there something - anything, how to get the result easily?

Edit: First of all i'm not dealing with Node environment or some JS script. I know how to deal with them there. I'm dealing with Fixrefox dev tools console and i'm looking for some simple way how to wait for promises to resolve. I know that i can do IIFE. That can be done for one or two promises but not for dozen of them simply because that is A LOT of code. I want something like:

```
function = resolvePromise(promise) { ... };
```

which just blocks until the promise is resolved and returns the resolved value. So i can then use it simply as:

```
var result = resolvePromise(promise); // result now holds the actual value
```

It doesn't have to be function and can be some hack because that won't be used in scripts or Node but only in dev tools. Writing IIFE in console for each promise is just horrible ergonomics.

Edit2: @Andy suggested to use Promise.all but as i don't have all the promises at the same time it's not an option. Basically i'm in a REPL where i need an short and easy way how to eval/inspect/store/decide what to do next and then repeat. I can't write IIFE all the time

Thanks

Comment: You could just use an async IIFE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of resolved Promise in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432908/get-value-of-resolved-promise-in-sync)

Comment: I can use IIFE if i'm dealing with one or two promises. But if a plan to spend some time in the console i really don't want to do it

Answer (score 0):

[`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is the best modern way to solve this.

```js
// Mock fetch function to return data
// after 2s
function fetch() {
  const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(n), 1000);
  });
}

// Push a load of promises into an array
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  arr.push(fetch());
}

// async immediately-invoked function expression.
// `Promise.all` gathers up all the results of all
// the promises in the array and returns its own promise
// and `await` pauses until that promise resolves
(async () => {
  console.log('Please wait for the result');
  const result = await Promise.all(arr);
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: Hi, yes, thanks, that can be done for one or two promises but not for dozen of them. Is it somehow possible to wrap this in a function so it can be then called like `var result = iife(promise); // result now holds the actual value`?

Comment: @PremyslDonat No! asynchronous functions return an AsyncFunction object. You still have to use `then` or `await` with the result.

Comment: @PremyslDonat, if you have loads of promises put them in an array and use `Promise.all` to wait til they've completed and then return the result. `Promise.all` returns a promise so you can still use `await`. I've updated my answer if that's any use.

Comment: @Andy thanks for your time but i don't have them all together at the same time. Do you work in a REPL sometimes? You write one line of code, wait for evaluation, inspect the result, store it in some variable and then repeat... much faster and flexible response time than constantly rewriting and re-running some script.